# Trying to implement remove* in Dr. Racket?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

```
(define (removeAll list-a list-b)
  (if (empty? list-b)
    list-a
    (apply
      (removeAll((remove (first list-b) list-a) (rest list-b)))
    )
  )
)
```

`(removeAll '(a b b c c d) '(a c a))`

expected output is `'(b b d)` in  this case

I can use remove but I can't use remove* itself. Currently I'm getting this error: 
`application: 
not a procedure; expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: '(b b c c d)
arguments...:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute your program in DrRacket you will obtain the error message with a clear evidence of its reason:

[image]

You see that the problem is inside:

```
((remove (first list-b) list-a) (rest list-b)))
```

The reason is that in scheme you **cannot** use the parentheses freely like in other languages: `(+ 2 (+ 3 4))` is not equal to `(+ 2 ((+ 3 4)))`: the first expression is evaluated to 9, the second gives an error since `((+ 3 4))` is interpreted in this way:

1. Evaluate the inner form (expression) `(+ 3 4)`, that is apply the operation `+` to the arguments 3 and 4, producing 7.
2. Since `(+ 3 4)` is inside another set of parentheses, than get the result and try to evaluate `(7)` as a form. But `7` is *not* an operator (“not a procedure”, as the error message says), so an error is raised.

In your case, the result of `remove` is a list, and this cannot be used as an operator.

If you remove the double parentheses, in this way:

```
(removeAll (remove (first list-b) list-a) (rest list-b))
```

you will remove the first error, and you will see that there is another error, in particular:

```
apply: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: at least 2
  given: 1
  arguments.:
```

Here is a possible solution:

```
(define (removeAll list-a list-b)
  (if (empty? list-b)
      list-a
      (removeAll (filter (lambda (x) (not (eq? (first list-b) x))) list-a) (rest list-b))))
```

The function `filter` remove all the elements that do not satisfy the predicate.

Comment: To put it slightly differently; adding parens *around* an expression in scheme or racket is like putting an empty pair *after* an expression in some other language. So if (a b) is like a(b), then ((a b)) is like a(b)(). This might be legal Java expression... but only if a(b) returns a function of no arguments.

Comment: @JohnClements Thanks! So close, but I'm getting `'(b b c d)` instead of `(b b d)`

Comment: @hello, I made  a mistake thinking that `remove` would remove all the occurrences of an element, instead it removes only the first occurrence, so I changed my answer